# Show Dialog on React material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui's [Dialog component](http://material-ui.com/#/components/dialog) for my React application. How do I set my component to a variable so that I can call the `onShow()` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When adding the `Dialog` component, just add a ref to it (`ref="dialog"` for example):

```
<Dialog ref="dialog" title="..." actions="...">
  dialog content
</Dialog>
```

And then you can reference it from your owner component code by using `this.refs.dialog.onShow(...)`.

The [Dialog component](http://material-ui.com/#/components/dialog) page actually uses refs behind the scenes, as you can see from its [source code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/pages/components/dialog.jsx#L236).

Comment: `onShow` is now deprecated: http://material-ui.com/#/components/dialog and opening should be handled through the `open` prop

Comment: In all the examples it shows a button with dialog on it to launch what if I want to launch in the way the OP is asking for AND hide the dialog button..

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading [Dan Abramov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623656/how-can-i-display-a-modal-dialog-in-redux-that-performs-asynchronous-actions/35641680) on how to implement a modal in React.

In order to use material-ui dialog you can replace the *DeletePostModal* in his example with the following:

```
import { deletePost, hideModal } from '../actions';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Button, Dialog, DialogActions, DialogTitle} from "material-ui";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const DeletePostModal = ({ post, dispatch }) => (
  <Dialog open={true}>
       <DialogTitle>Delete post {post.name}?</DialogTitle>
            <DialogActions>
                 <button onClick={() => {
                      dispatch(deletePost(post.id)).then(() => {
                           dispatch(hideModal());
                      });
                  }}>
                        Yes
                  </button>
                  <button onClick={() => dispatch(hideModal())}>
                        Nope
                  </button>
        </DialogActions>
   </Dialog>
)

export default connect(
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    post: state.postsById[ownProps.postId]
  })
)(DeletePostModal)
```