# React-Redux container throws "mapStateToProps() in Connect(ModalRoot) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, redux, react-redux

I am building a Redux based Model/Dialog trigger based on Dan Abramov's solution to this question: [Dan Abramov's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623656/how-can-i-display-a-modal-dialog-in-redux-that-performs-asynchronous-actions/35641680)

The error I am getting is "mapStateToProps() in Connect(ModalRoot) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined."

---

Here is the code for the modal container and the code that calls it:

```
// Code that calls the Modal Container

import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Connector as HorizonConnector } from 'horizon-react';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

import routes from '../routes';
import store from '../store';
import horizon from '../db';
import ModalRoot from './Modal';

export default () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <HorizonConnector horizon={horizon} store={store}>
      <div className="app">
        {routes}
        <ModalRoot />
      </div>
    </HorizonConnector>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

---

```
 // The Modal Container
 import LoginModal from '../components/Modals/LoginModal'
 import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const MODAL_COMPONENTS = {
  'LOGIN_MODAL': LoginModal
  /* other modals */
}

const ModalRoot = ({ modalType, modalProps }) => {
  if (!modalType) {
    return <span /> // after React v15 you can return null here
  }

  const SpecificModal = MODAL_COMPONENTS[modalType]
  return <SpecificModal {...modalProps} />
}

export default connect(
  state => state.modal
)(ModalRoot)
```

---

Its probably something simple i'm forgetting but its driving me crazy, any comments or suggestions welcome.

Comment: Have you checked that the state.modal actually exists? Using redux dev tools?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, it does not. Not really sure what I'm supposed to do to create it. Am I missing a step?

Comment: If you go through Dan's answer again you will see that you need to create a `modalReducer`, and then have fired actions that gets consumed by the reducer.  If you are unfamiliar with redux, give Dan's lessons a go: https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: Here is my actionCreators: [link](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8874321)

Comment: Here is my reducer: [link](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8874323) which is combined with combineRecucers

Comment: Reducer looks fine, your combineReducers implementation may be incorrect.

Comment: this is my index reducer which consists of the combineReducers function: [link](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8874326)

Comment: Okay, again that looks good. Is your redux store being created before the rendering occurs? And is your app surrounded by the redux Provider component?

Comment: My project is built on the "Lovli.js" boilerplate for using Horizon and React/redux. Instead of using the Provider component it uses HorizonConnector from the horizon-react library that serves the same purpose as Provider. e.g passing the store down the hierarchy but it also does it with the horizon object

Comment: Awesome! I am just wanting to get into Horizon. I'll be keeping an eye on this. :) Hmmm... I would compare your init functions against the boilerplate. If they don't differ it may be worth pinging an issue on their github.

Comment: Yeah I think thats the only option at the moment, there doesn't seem to be any evidence of this happening anywhere else, also i dont think i mentioned this in the original post but this is crashing the page causing a white screen.

Comment: Actually after looking in Redux Dev Tools I can see that state.modal doesn't exist despite the modal reducer, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

According to redux implementation and example you should write like this

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    modal: state.modal
  })
)(ModalRoot)
```

See [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

Comment: Umm, it only needs to return a plain object, which is what state.modal is supposed to contain...

Comment: See `const ModalRoot = ({ modalType, modalProps })` which is a result of props likely from `modal.modalType` and `modal.modalProps`.

Comment: Hmmm, do you have a default state of modal?

Comment: Using Michael's method causes the following error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: getNodeFromInstance: Invalid argument.invariant

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo , by default state do you mean the default parameter for state passed in to the reducer?

Comment: I'm not the OP.  But yes, he does have an initial state set.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps mapStateToProps needs to pick a specific object from your reducer

Could you try something like this?

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  const {modalType,modalProps} = state.modal;
  return {modalType,modalProps};
}
```

Its either this or perhaps you arent properly passing combineReducers to your store

Comment: Thanks @Kunkka for the response, doing your suggested method eliminates the error from the console but rendering the container still results in a crash/white screen

Comment: Strangely, there isn't!?

Comment: do you have the chrome react tools installed? I usually check that to see if the provider is initialized

Comment: provider is initialised @kunkka

Comment: I actually believe that the problem is with the state updating as dispatching an action has no effect on state but also state.modal is never made from from the reducers initial state.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that `state.modal` is undefined. You can get more info by adding a simple log statement like:

```
export default connect(state => { console.log('state', state); return state.modal })(ModalRoot)
```

This may help you see what's in `state` and help in figuring out *why* `state.modal` is undefined.

To make this error go away, you can use either of these 2 solutions:

**Ensuring the object is not undefined:**

```
export default connect(state => state.modal || {})(ModalRoot)
```

**Using ES6 destructuring:**

```
export default connect(({ modal }) => ({ modal }))(ModalRoot)
```

If you use the ES6 destructuring (which is essentially same as @MichaelRasoahaingo's solution), your prop destructuring will also change to:

```
const ModalRoot = ({ modal: { modalType, modalProps } }) => {
```

Or you can use this alternative syntax and keep your destructuring as is:

```
export default connect(({ modal }) => ({ ...modal }))(ModalRoot)
```