# React js: Open same modal from different components

Tags: reactjs, redux, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a Modal, say 'modal for user login', from different components in my React app. For ex: I want the modal to open from `A.js`, `B.js` and `C.js`. So I made a new component `ModalWindow.js` which contains the modal and I imported it in `A.js`, `B.js` and `C.js`.

Now the issue is that I got to maintain state `showModal: false` in all 3 components for Modal to show/hide. Is there anyway that I have to maintain a single state.

One way is that I maintain state in the parent component. But is there any better way possible?

`X.js`

```
import A from 'A.js'
import B from 'B.js'
import C from 'C.js'

class X extends Component {
  return(
    render{
      <div>
        <A />
        <B />
        <C />
      </div>
    }
  )
}

export default X
```

`A.js`

```
import ModalWindow from 'ModalWindow.js'

class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }
  return(
    render{
      <ModalWindow show={this.state.showModal} container={this}/>
    }
  )
}

export default A
```

`B.js`

```
import ModalWindow from 'ModalWindow.js'

class B extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }
  return(
    render{
      <ModalWindow show={this.state.showModal} container={this}/>
    }
  )
}

export default B
```

`C.js`

```
import ModalWindow from 'ModalWindow.js'

class C extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }
  return(
    render{
      <ModalWindow show={this.state.showModal} container={this}/>
    }
  )
}

export default C
```

`ModalWindow.js`

```
import Modal from 'Bootstrap/Modal'

class ModalWindow extends Component {
  return(
    render{
      <Modal
      show={this.props.showModal}
      container={this.props.container}
      bsSize='small'
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton="true">
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">
          Login
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        Login Here
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
    }
  )
}

export default ModalWindow
```

Comment: If you are using Redux you can hold the state in a Redux store and then dispatch actions in the child components to show it - but I wouldn't recommend implementing Redux just for this purpose.

Comment: I use redux already.

Comment: Well a common approach I take is to keep a "display" reducer which handles various states of display. Then I have an action which takes in a message that shows the modal with the message. Then in the modal itself I might have a button that, onClick, fires an action that hides the modal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly recommend the approach that Dan Abramov described in [How can I display a modal dialog in Redux that performs asynchronous actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623656/how-can-i-display-a-modal-dialog-in-redux-that-performs-asynchronous-actions/35641680#35641680) .  Basically, have a central component that is responsible for displaying modals, and dispatch actions that give the name of the modal to open and any values to pass along as props.

Answer (score 7):

You can have the `state` inside the modal and expose two functions to open/close modal which will change the state. Those functions can be accessed via `refs` in other components.See the example below.

**ModalWindow.js**

```
import Modal from 'Bootstrap/Modal'

class ModalWindow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
    }
  }
  show() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true,
    })
  }
  hide() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true,
    })
  }
  render() {
    return <Modal
    show={this.state.showModal}
    container={this.props.container}
    bsSize='small'>
      < Modal.Header closeButton = "true" >
      < Modal.Title id = "contained-modal-title" >
      Login < /Modal.Title> < /Modal.Header> < Modal.Body >
      Login Here < /Modal.Body> < /Modal>
  }
}

export default ModalWindow
```

**A.js, B.js, C.js**

```
import ModalWindow from 'ModalWindow.js'

class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.modal.show() //to show the modal
    this.refs.modal.hide() //to hide the modal
  }
  render() {
    return <ModalWindow container={this} ref = "modal" / >
  }
}

export default A
```