# Realize a confirm component with react, redux and promise

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I try to build a generic confirm component with redux and native promise. I read Dan Abramovs solution here: [How can I display a modal dialog in Redux that performs asynchronous actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623656/how-can-i-display-a-modal-dialog-in-redux-that-performs-asynchronous-actions/35641680#35641680) but i am looking for a more generic appoach.
Basically i want to do this:

```js
confirm({
  type: 'warning',
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  description: 'Would you like to do this action?',
  confirmLabel: 'Yes',
  abortLabel: 'Abort'
})
.then(() => {
  // do something after promise is resolved
})
```

The confirm method basically opens the modal and returns a promise. Inside the promise i subscribe my redux store, listen for state changes and resolve or reject the promise:

```js
export const confirm = function(settings) {
  // first dispatch openConfirmModal with given props
  store.dispatch(
    openConfirmModal({
      ...settings
    })
  );

  // return a promise that subscribes to redux store
  // see: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe
  // on stateChanges check for resolved/rejected
  // if resolved or rejected:
  // - dispatch closeConfirmModal
  // - resolve or reject the promise
  // - unsubscribe to store
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    function handleStateChange() {
      let newState = store.getState();

      if (newState.confirmModal.resolved) {
        store.dispatch(closeConfirmModal());
        resolve();
        unsubscribe();
      }

      if (newState.confirmModal.rejected) {
        store.dispatch(closeConfirmModal());
        reject();
        unsubscribe();
      }
    }

    let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleStateChange);
  })


}
```

My confirm component is connected to redux store and is included once in some kind of layout component - so it is useable on all routes in the app:

```js
class ConfirmModal extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  confirm() {
    this.props.dispatch(resolveConfirmModal());
  }

  abort() {
    this.props.dispatch(rejectConfirmModal());
  }

  render() {
    // my modal window 
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    confirmModal: state.confirmModal
  })
)(ConfirmModal);
```

Reducer/Action looks like this:

```js
export const openConfirmModal = (settings) => {
  return {
    type: 'OPEN_CONFIRM_MODAL',
    settings
  };
};

export const resolveConfirmModal = () => {
  return {
    type: 'RESOLVE_CONFIRM_MODAL'
  };
};

export const rejectConfirmModal = () => {
  return {
    type: 'REJECT_CONFIRM_MODAL'
  };
};

export const closeConfirmModal = () => {
  return {
    type: 'CLOSE_CONFIRM_MODAL'
  };
};

const initialState = {
  open: false,
  type: 'info',
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  description: 'Are you sure you want to do this action?',
  confirmLabel: 'Yes',
  abortLabel: 'Abort',
};

export const ConfirmModalReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'OPEN_CONFIRM_MODAL':
      return { ...action.settings, open: true };

    case 'RESOLVE_CONFIRM_MODAL':
      return { ...state, resolved: true };

    case 'REJECT_CONFIRM_MODAL':
      return { ...state, rejected: true };

    case 'CLOSE_CONFIRM_MODAL':
      return initialState;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The redux part is working. My confirm window can be open/closed and renders depending on my options. But how i can define a promise in my confirm method that can be resolved in my component? How i get everything connected?

## Found a working Solution!

Found a solution that is pretty much what i was looking for:

- The modal properties are driven by my Redux state
- The modal component is included once AND it lives inside my
  applicition not as a different rendered app like
  here:http://blog.arkency.com/2015/04/beautiful-confirm-window-with-react/
- The confirm method returns a native promise that is
  resolved/rejected driven by Redux state

What do you think?

Comment: Can you add `closeConfirmModal()` code please?

Comment: Done. Actions and reducer are added. Maybe it would a better approach to use async actions. But to this point i tried to keep it simple on the redux part.

Comment: @d-bro82 do you have this example in javascript instead of cofeescript?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it, but it won't be pretty. Basically, you need a map of outstanding promises next to your `confirm()`:

```
var outstandingModals = {}
const confirm = function(settings) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let id = uuid.v4();
        outstandingModals = resolve;
        store.dispatch(
        openConfirmModal({
            ...settings,
            confirmationId: id,
        })
    );
}
```

and then later:

```
case 'CLOSE_CONFIRM_MODAL':
    let resolve = outstandingModals[state.confirmationId];
    if (resolve) {
        resolve();
        delete outstandingModals[state.confirmationId];
    }
    return initialState;
```

Like I said - ugly. I don't think you can do much better than that using promises.

But you can do better by NOT using promises. What I would do is simply render a Confirm component whenever necessary, say:

```
render() {
    return <div>
       ... My stuff ...
        {confirmationNecessary && <Confirm text='Are you sure?' onAction={this.thenConfirmed}/>}
       </div>
}
```

`confirmationNecessary` can come from `this.state` or from the store.

Comment: Thank you very much. But with this approach i have to pass my actions to my confirm-component and i have to include the confirm-component  in every other component where i want to show a confirm. This is what i am trying to avoid. My Idea was a component that is included once  AND don't need to know what to do after confirm. Basically like http://jameskleeh.com/angular-confirm/

Comment: That's okay. You could at least use the first option that I suggested - with the `outstandingPromises` map. I wouldn't really use redux for it though. I'd implement something custom, that uses react's `context` property.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post that discusses one possible approach for managing "generic" modals like this: [Posts on PacktPub: "Generic Redux Modals" and "Building Better Bundles"](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/11/posts-on-packtpub-generic-redux-modals-and-building-better-bundles/).

The basic idea is that the code that requested the modal can include a pre-written action as a prop, and the modal can dispatch that action once it's closed.

There's also an interesting-looking library at [redux-promising-modals](https://github.com/AKolodeev/redux-promising-modals) that appears to implement modal result promises through middleware.

Comment: Thank you, i also read Dan Abramovs approach on StackOverflow. Your Blogpost is very interesting and i like the idea to dispatch with action as payload. I will give it a try but i am missing the promise part :/

Comment: Yeah, my approach avoids promises and callbacks in favor of dispatching an action when done.  If you really want a promise, you might try that `promising-modals` library.

Answer (score 0):

possible so :)

```js
export const MsgBox = {
 okCancel : s =>
  new Promise((ok, cancel) =>
   confirm(s) ? ok() : cancel() ),

......etc
```