# Making a Modal component independent from parent state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My react project uses redux, but in order to trigger a "Confirm Delete" modal inside a parent I'm using the parent state to trigger the modal.

I could link the modal to the redux store, but both these methods feel like very convoluted ways of actioning the delete.

Ideally, I'd like the modal to be set up independently of state/redux, so that I can simply trigger a `runModal(body, clear, callback)` function in the `button` onClick Handler before confirming the delete.

What am I missing?

```
// Parent Component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions.js';

import MyModal from '../../modal';

class EditUser extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            modal: {
                body:null,
                callback:null,
                clear: null,
            }
        }
    }


    clearModal = () => { this.setState({modal: false}) }


    handleUserDelete = (id, index) => {
        let body = "Permanently delete user?";
        this.setState({
            modal: {
                body,
                callback:()=> { this.props.deleteUser(id, index) },
                clear: this.clearModal,
            }
        })
    }


    render() {
        const { updateUser,  user } = this.props;
        return(
            <MyModal
                {...this.state.modal}
                />
            <button 
                className="btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
                onClick={() => this.handleUserDelete(user.ID, user.index)}
                >Remove</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps ({ account }) {
    const { user } = account;
    return { user };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(EditUser);
```

-

```
// Child Component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';


class MyModal extends Component {
    render (){
        const {
            title,
            body,
            callback,
            clear,
        } = this.props;
        if ( callback && body ) {
            return (
                <div className="w-100">
                    <Modal.Dialog>
                        {title &&                   
                        <Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Title>{title}</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        }
                        <Modal.Body>{body}</Modal.Body>
                        <Modal.Footer>
                            <button 
                                className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" 
                                onClick={()=> {clear()}}
                                >Close</button>
                            <button 
                                className="btn-sm btn-danger"
                                onClick={()=> {
                                    callback();
                                    clear();
                                }}
                                >Confirm</button>
                        </Modal.Footer>
                    </Modal.Dialog>
                </div>
            )
        }
        return null;
    }
}

export default MyModal
```

Comment: have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641680/3148807)?

Comment: I'm more looking to use it within components, rather than being able to call them globally, but I hadn't seen this and it proved very interesting as part or research, thanks!