# Is it okay to store/pass "function" to Redux store in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am making modal by referring to the link below with react hook.

[How can I display a modal dialog in Redux that performs asynchronous actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623656/how-can-i-display-a-modal-dialog-in-redux-that-performs-asynchronous-actions)

The state of the modal is managed by Redux.
I want to run some "function" when the modal is closed. However, this "function" should only work on a specific component, so when I open a modal in a specific component, I want to pass this "function" to the modal. But I'm not sure is it okay to pass and store the "function" to Redux.
I did a lot of searches, but still I'm not sure.

I would really appreciate if someone would let me know if this is correct or not.
Thanks for your reading.

SpecificComponent.jsx

```
const saySomthing = () => {
   console.log("Now modal is close.");
}

const openModal = () => {
    dispatch({
       type: SHOW_MODAL, 
       modalProps: {
             handleClose: saySomthing
    })
}
```

Modal.jsx

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const modalProps = useSelctor((state) => state.modal.modalProps);

const handleClose = () => {
    modalProps.handleClose();
    dispatch({type: HIDE_MODAL});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that. Put a non serializable data in the Redux store state you can get more details in the [Redux Best Practice Documentation](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).

**You can do that but that can bring in some unexpected behavior**

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
If so, do I have to store all the specific modal's state in redux store and then run function(eg. saySomthing() in my question) in reducer?

Comment: You can save the state of the modal **(HIDDEN || SHOW)** in the Redux store state, and based on that value you can specify how you handle the event which switch the state of the modal from hidden to show.