# Where is the root of my component hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a modal for my React / Redux application and found [some great answers in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623656/how-can-i-display-a-modal-dialog-in-redux-that-performs-asynchronous-actions/35641680).

One thing I cannot figure out though is where "the root of [my] component hierarchy" is.

My application is structured as below:

`app.js`

```
const jsx = (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
)
```

`AppRouter.js`

```
...
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <LoadingSpinnerFullPage />
    <Router history={history}>
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinnerFullPage />}>
        <div className="appContainer">
          <Route exact path={SidebarLocation.path} render={(props) => privatePath({component: Sidebar})} />
            <div className="app-MainContent content-container-parent ">
              <Route exact path={HeaderLocation.path} render ={(props) => privatePath({component: Header, ...props})} />
              <Switch>
```

Where would my component "hierarchy root" be considered to be located?

Is it

- directly under `<React.Fragment>` ?
- alongside all routes directly under `< Router >` ?
- at the same level as `< AppRouter />` in app.js inside `< Provider >` ?

If my modal is connected to the redux store listening to `modal.isOpen` - would placing it in the Router cause re-rendering of my entire app each time the modal is opened or closed?

Many thanks! /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that you pass to `ReactDOM.render` is technically the "root" of your component hierarchy, which I'm guessing would be `<React.StrictMode>` here (assuming you call it with the `jsx` variable).

If your modal is connected to the Redux store, then it *must* be rendered somewhere inside the react-redux `<Provider>` element (even though that's not technically your root here).

I would suggest rendering it as a child of `<Provider>`, alongside the `<AppRouter>` component. That's the closest it can be to the root element without having to couple it to one of your other components.

You may need to wrap them both in a fragment to keep the `Provider` component happy.

```js
const jsx = (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <React.Fragment>
        <AppRouter />
        <ModalRoot />
      </React.Fragment>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```